# Setting text SVG element dynamically via javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am creating SVG elements via JavaScript, and it works fine, but when I create an text SVG element and define it's content, the browser just don't render the value, despite the value is in the code when I inspect it with firebug.

The code is:

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
svg.setAttribute('xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
svg.setAttribute('width','187');
svg.setAttribute('height','234');

var rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
rect.setAttribute('width','187');
rect.setAttribute('height','234');
rect.setAttribute('fill','#fff');
rect.setAttribute('stroke','#000');
rect.setAttribute('stroke-width','2');
rect.setAttribute('rx','7');

var text = document.createElementNS('ttp://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
text.setAttribute('x', '10');
text.setAttribute('y', '20');
text.setAttribute('fill', '#000');
text.textContent = '2';

svg.appendChild(rect);
svg.appendChild(text); 

var wp = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
wp.appendChild(svg);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sAhyC/).
If you inspect the SVG you will see the value of the text element there, but the browser doesn't render it.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that "dynamically" is not the problem here.

Comment: User failed to show "research effort". Upvotting as this is the perfect reference for "how to add dynamic textto a svg image?" kudos ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're short an "h" in your namespace

Was

```
var text = document.createElementNS('ttp://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
```

should be

```
var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
```

Comment: Yeah! That's right! I have readed that code countless times, but I hadn't noticesd that. Thank you very mutch

Answer (score 12):

```
    function createText() {

  var newText = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
  newText.setAttributeNS(null,"x",20);      
  newText.setAttributeNS(null,"y",100);   
  var textNode = document.createTextNode("milind morey");
  newText.appendChild(textNode);
  document.getElementById("firstGroup").appendChild(newText);
}
```

---

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300">    
       <g id="firstGroup">

    <text x="20" y="45" onclick="createText();" font-size=+13px">Click on this text to create a new text.</text>

  </g>
       </svg>
```

Comment: is this still the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I compress your code a little now it works

```js
let txt='2';

wrapper.innerHTML=`
  <svg xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="187" height="234">
    <rect width="187" height="234" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" 
          stroke-width="2" rx="7"></rect>
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="#000">${txt}</text>
  </svg>
`;
```

```html
<div id=wrapper></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You did a very simple mistake:

var text = document.createElementNS('ttp://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
                                     ^^^
compared to

var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
                                     ^^^^
Hit the keyboard!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! This question has already been answered and the typo noticed. There is no need to submit duplicate answers.